# Java Maven Tomcat7:run java memory options for jvm

Tags: java, tomcat, memory, jvm

my question is right complicated for me. I am running a server for a game and i have some problems setting up the java settings for memory correctly.

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 64bit with 32 gb ram.

The java task should take up to 20 gb of real memory. Instead of doing it it uses virtual memory all the time.

```
top - 19:51:44 up 15 min,  1 user,  load average: 0.29, 0.30, 0.19
Tasks: 120 total,   2 running, 118 sleeping,   0 stopped,   0 zombie
Cpu(s):  0.9%us,  0.3%sy,  0.0%ni, 98.5%id,  0.2%wa,  0.0%hi,  0.0%si,  0.0%st
Mem:  32809368k total,  2237888k used, 30571480k free,    28092k buffers
Swap: 16776116k total,        0k used, 16776116k free,   411660k cached

PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
1876 test      20   0 46.1g 1.2g  15m S    8  3.7   1:37.17 java
```

currently i am running it with this command:
    MAVEN_OPTS="-Xnoagent -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8000 -Xmx20480M" screen -S Test -d -m mvn -o tomcat7:run

I also tried to add it to the pom.xml (build selection):

```
    <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>exec</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <argLine>-Xmx20480m</argLine>
                <mainClass>org.server.Server</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Would be very nice if anyone knows a solution for this.

Thank you very much.

Edit: /proc/{pid}/ ls -l
I cant answer to your comment directly but i dont understand where this mmap is exactly.
Thats what i get when i switch into the folder you wrote:

```
    root@testserver /proc/1876 # ls -l
    total 0
    dr-xr-xr-x   2 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 attr
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 autogroup
    -r--------   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 auxv
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 cgroup
    --w-------   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 clear_refs
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 cmdline
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 comm
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 19:37 coredump_filter
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 cpuset
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0 Nov 10 19:39 cwd -> /srv/main
    -r--------   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 environ
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0 Nov 10 19:37 exe -> /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java
    dr-x------   2 root root 0 Nov 10 19:39 fd
    dr-x------   2 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 fdinfo
    -r--------   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 io
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 latency
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 limits
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 loginuid
    dr-x------   2 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 map_files
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 19:37 maps
    -rw-------   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 mem
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 mountinfo
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 mounts
    -r--------   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 mountstats
    dr-xr-xr-x   5 root root 0 Nov 10 19:37 net
    dr-x--x--x   2 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 ns
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 numa_maps
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 oom_adj
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 oom_score
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 oom_score_adj
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 pagemap
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 personality
    lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root 0 Nov 10 19:39 root -> /
    -rw-r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 sched
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 schedstat
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 sessionid
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 smaps
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 stack
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 19:37 stat
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 19:37 statm
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 status
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 syscall
    dr-xr-xr-x 627 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 task
    -r--r--r--   1 root root 0 Nov 10 20:15 wchan
```

Edit 2:
Maps file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BxN3fm0mPOMUMVF1X0VEc2NSWVU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Why do you think it should use 20GB? does your program allocate that much memory? If so, why do you think it should be swapped in? is the program touching all of that memory?

Comment: Just in case, 20GB heap would mean stop-the-world for several tens of seconds for modern GC collectors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work out where the extra virtual memory is coming from.  The heap is not the only memory used but the JVM or your application.

I suggest you look at `/proc/{pid}/maps` to see if the virtual memory is coming from memory mapped files, thread stacks or native memory.

How many threads do you have as these can contribute a lot (if you have thousands)

If you have memory mapped files, this could easily be hundreds of GB of virtual memory. Given your entire system is actually using 2 GB of memory, I would suspect large memory mappings as these often use a lot of virtual memory without using read memory.  You should be able to see this in `maps` easily as it includes the path to each memory mapped file.

Here is a program you can use to decode the mapping.  Run this with

```
java -cp . Main /proc/{pid}/maps
```

---

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(args[0]));
        List<Mapping> mappings = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String line; (line = br.readLine()) != null; ) {
            mappings.add(new Mapping(line));
        }
        Collections.sort(mappings);
        for (Mapping mapping : mappings) {
            System.out.println(mapping);
        }
    }

    static class Mapping implements Comparable<Mapping> {
        final String details;
        final long size;

        Mapping(String details) {
            this.details = details;
            String[] words = details.split("[- ]");
            long size = 0;
            try {
                if (words.length > 2)
                size = new BigInteger(words[1], 16).longValue() - new BigInteger(words[0], 16).longValue();
            } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                // ignored.
            }
            this.size = size;
        }

        @Override
        public int compareTo(Mapping o) {
            // reverse order.
            return -Long.compare(size, o.size);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return String.format("%.3f %s", size / 1024.0 / 1024, details);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have edited my question with the /proc/{pid} ls -l

There is no mmap thing.

Comment: @user2976847 Sorry, that should be `maps`

Comment: The Server starts lagging more and more over time. And i dont know why. We dont have so much data files that could cause 40 gb of virtual ram. the servers data files are max 10 mb.

Comment: @user2976847 Can you provide a copy of your `maps`?  Perhaps you are using more than you think, or mapping the same files multiple times. BTW `gb` = grams-bits and `mb` = milli-bits.

Comment: i have added the maps file in my question post

Comment: @user2976847 I have updated my answer and according the `maps` file your largest memory regions is ~ 4 MB which is your native heap.  Are you sure you have the right process?

Comment: Can you check the `/proc/{pid}/cmdline` ?

Comment: i am running the java process in screen. But i only have one java process running.

Comment: the cmdline says:
/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/bin/java.-Xmx20480M.-XX:MaxPermSize=20480M.-classpath./usr/share/maven/boot/plexus-classworlds-2.x.jar.-Dclassworlds.conf=/usr/share/maven/bin/m2.conf.-Dmaven.home=/usr/share/maven.org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.-o.tomcat7:run.

Comment: In that case, I can't explain why the virtual memory in `top` is so much larger than it appears in `maps` as they have always worked out to be about the same for me.